# Broadleaf Jboss Setup ClassNoFound

Tags: jboss, broadleaf-commerce

When trying to do a broadleaf Jboss setup, I am getting the below error

I have checked the source code com.broadleafcommerce.customersegment.admin.dataimport.persistence.CustomerSegmentRecordPersistencePreProcessor is available in broadleaf-merchandising-group-1.2.1-GA.jar but strangely the class com.broadleafcommerce.dataimport.service.RecordPersistencePreProcessor is no where found, please help.

```
2018-01-02 21:51:54,565 WARN  [org.jboss.modules] (MSC service thread 1-7) Failed to define class com.broadleafcommerce.customersegment.admin.dataimport.persistence.CustomerSegmentRecordPersistencePreProcessor in Module "deployment.admin.war" from Service Module Loader: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed to link com/broadleafcommerce/customersegment/admin/dataimport/persistence/CustomerSegmentRecordPersistencePreProcessor (Module "deployment.admin.war" from Service Module Loader): com/broadleafcommerce/dataimport/service/RecordPersistencePreProcessor
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.defineClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:446)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:274)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader$1.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:77)
    at org.jboss.modules.Module.loadModuleClass(Module.java:713)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:190)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:412)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:400)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:116)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.ServletContainerInitializerDeploymentProcessor.loadClassInfoSet(ServletContainerInitializerDeploymentProcessor.java:259)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.ServletContainerInitializerDeploymentProcessor.deploy(ServletContainerInitializerDeploymentProcessor.java:169)
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:165)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:2032)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1955)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

2018-01-02 21:51:54,565 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-7) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."admin.war".INSTALL: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."admin.war".INSTALL: WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase INSTALL of deployment "admin.war"
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:172)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:2032)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1955)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed to link com/broadleafcommerce/customersegment/admin/dataimport/persistence/CustomerSegmentRecordPersistencePreProcessor (Module "deployment.admin.war" from Service Module Loader): com/broadleafcommerce/dataimport/service/RecordPersistencePreProcessor
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.defineClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:446)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:274)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader$1.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:77)
    at org.jboss.modules.Module.loadModuleClass(Module.java:713)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:190)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:412)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:400)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:116)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.ServletContainerInitializerDeploymentProcessor.loadClassInfoSet(ServletContainerInitializerDeploymentProcessor.java:259)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.ServletContainerInitializerDeploymentProcessor.deploy(ServletContainerInitializerDeploymentProcessor.java:169)
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:165)
    ... 5 more
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue that you are running into is the `ServletContextInitializer` scanning in Servlet 3.0+ containers. In Tomcat, you can control this with this guide: https://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/HowTo/FasterStartUp#JAR_scanning. Jboss is utilizing its class loader to check for `ServletContextInitializer` classes, and in some of the Broadleaf jars we link in at compile time some conditional classes that may not be available at runtime.

Are you using the Spring Boot project based on Broadleaf 5.2.x? You can try adding a web.xml that has an empty `<absolute-ordering />`: https://www.broadleafcommerce.com/docs/core/current/broadleaf-concepts/key-aspects-and-configuration/app-server-configuration/using-a-web.xml

I would also question the use of Jboss at all. There is almost zero reason to ever use a full-blown JEE application server within a Spring application and frankly, you are asking for more issues as time goes on. You are trying to combine a fat .war (a Spring application built with Maven) with a fat application server (jboss). You should instead pair a fat .war file with a light servlet container (like Tomcat) or a light .war file (a JEE application) with a JEE application server.

Comment: this decision doesn't belongs to us, i.e whether to use Jboss or not.